# Accessing and getting response from API call

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, parsing

I am checking out the namecheap api and am having some difficulty getting started. I am trying to access the api after setting up the sandbox account etc and a sample response is in XML format:

```
<ApiResponse Status="OK" xmlns="http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response">
  <Errors />
  <Warnings />
  <RequestedCommand>namecheap.domains.check</RequestedCommand>
  <CommandResponse>
    <DomainCheckResult Domain="google.com" Available="false" />
  </CommandResponse>
  <Server>WEB1-SANDBOX1</Server>
  <GMTTimeDifference>--4:00</GMTTimeDifference>
  <ExecutionTime>0.875</ExecutionTime>
</ApiResponse>
```

I know how to parse XML, but what I need a little guidance with is how do I get started with the actual request/response part of the API call.

I know which parameters I need to send, and I know I need the api key and url, but how do I write the WebRequest and WebResponse part of it? Or can Linq provide me a way to achieve that too?

I was trying to use:

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url + apikey + username + command + domain);
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

But I don't see a way to do anything with variable `response`.

How can I make a very simple API call to this API and get its response into XML format so I can parse it?

Any help at all is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the Response Stream associated and read from it:

```
// Get the stream associated with the response.
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

Console.WriteLine ("Response stream received.");
Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd ());
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It looks like the correct answer to me. readStream.ReadToEnd() will return a string of the content in the response.

Answer (score -2):

`WebResponse` is abstract, you must cast it to an `HttpWebResponse`.

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

You will then be able to access the various information inside that you're looking for.

---

Also, you might consider using a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) if you're just doing simple web requests, it's *much* easier to work with... literally as easy as:

```
string response = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://somewebsite.com/some/resource?params=123");
```

Comment: Thank you SpikeX but all that did was display `System.Net.HttpWebResponse` on the page. No response at all.

Comment: You didn't show the part of the code that was displaying anything, so I didn't help with that. If you want more help, you need to show more code. I can't read your mind.

Comment: @SpikeX why did you delete the comment from my post? The link you had originally posted from MSDN shows exactly the same code I posted -because that's where I got it from- so what is it that's wrong with my answer again?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, that's why I deleted my comment. I thought that would be obvious.

Comment: @Joey - you can't just do response.ToString() - you need to get the response stream, and read it, like in Icarus' answer.

Comment: I didn't see you removing the downvote as fast as you deleted your comment. That's why I asked. Your post does not answer the question and claims something that it's not entirely true, namely: `WebResponse is abstract, you must cast it to an HttpWebResponse.` You don't need to cast anything. Doing `WebResponse  response = request.GetResponse ();
           Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();` is perfectly fine. (-1) for not answering the question and misleading the OP.